# Ghost + Azure: Cannot read property '__cid' of undefined

Tags: node.js, azure, sqlite, ghost-blog

New to ghost, and new to NodeJS, but couldn't resist trying to set Ghost up.

**Goal:** Get  a new ghost instance up and running on Azure from source.

I followed [Scott Hanselman's Post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToInstallTheNodejsGhostBloggingSoftwareOnAzureWebsites.aspx) and [Jeremiah Billmann's Post](http://www.jbillmann.com/installing-ghost-on-azure-web-sites/) to attempt this.

I did the following:

- Installed node, ruby, grunt-cli in my local environment
- Performed a git clone of https://github.com/TryGhost/ghost.git into a folder in my downloads folder
- Copied all files (except the .git folder) into my repository's root
- Opened a command line in my repo's root
- Ran `npm install`
- Ran `grunt init`
- Ran `grunt prod`
- Created a `server.js` file in the root directory that contained `var GhostServer = require('./index');`

  - (i understand this is required for Azure)
- Renamed `config.example.js` to `config.js` and edited its properties

  - NOTE: Did not touch anything in database (sqlite3) section
- Edited the .gitignore to stop ignoring assets, config.js, and /core/built
- Committed to Bitbucket
- Azure picked up on it and deployed
- I ran it, and got a 500-style error message
- I edited the `iisnode.yml` file to have it output full errors

The full error I see is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '__cid' of undefined
    at Runner_SQLite3.<anonymous>
```

Screenshot of the full error is below:
[image]

Any idea where I went wrong on this? The nature of the error message makes me suspect it's not me, but given that I'm new to this I could be completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a very similar problem with a fresh upgrade on a standard linux box. It seems like sqlite3 chokes on a non-existing path for its database.

Try that:

1. Make sure that the `/content/data` directory exists (or whatever path you have set in your config file for the `ghost-dev.db` file). If not, create it.

   *Normally, this should do the trick. If not, then maybe you need to force migrations via step 2 below.*
2. Try running :

`FORCE_MIGRATION=true npm start`

Answer (score 0):

Ghost (0.5.3) includes, in config.js, the following path by default:

```
database: {
        client: 'sqlite3',
        connection: {
            filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost-dev.db')
        },
        debug: false
    },
```

Run the following series of commands, from the root directory of Ghost, to create the file path and file sqlite3 requires:

```
cd content
mkdir data
cd data
touch ghost-dev.db
../../
npm start
```

FYI: this can happen if the following line is included in your .gitignore file

```
/content/data/*
```